# How to get width of a div in percentage using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div, and I'd like to know if there's a way to get its width in percentage using jQuery.

**Here's my code**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var f = $('.f').width();
      alert(f);    
});
```

I tried to use `%` as an argument like this `width(%)`, but this is setting the width as `%` not getting the value in a percentage format. Can someone tell me what should I do to get in percentage instead?

Any help is profusely appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXRxP/)

Comment: Width is only ever given as an absolute value in pixels. To convert this to `%` you need to get the width of the parent element and do some maths.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To use your example code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var f = $(".f").width() / $('.f').parent().width() * 100;
   alert(f);    
});
```

[Working jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/aXRxP/4/)

Comment: +1 for this version for the use of `parent()`, over hard-coding a selector.

Comment: Anyone struggling to calculate the width of element that have borders: add `parseFloat($('.f').css('border-width')) * 2` to the elements' width on the left side of the division

Comment: @BrunoPeres see jquery's method `outerWidth()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the width relative to the body:

```
var percent =  $('.f').width() / $('body').width() * 100;

console.log(Math.round(percent).toFixed(2));
```

Is this what you're asking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/aXRxP/5/

Answer (score 1):

you will need to get viewport width and then calculate your element width percentage in accordance with viewport width.

```
var width = $('#someElt').width();
var parentWidth = $('#someElt').offsetParent().width(); // this will return parent element's width which also can be replaced with docuent to get viewport width
var percent = 100*width/parentWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var f = $('.f').width();
    var pw = $('.f').parent().width();
    var rate = (f/pw*100) + '%';
    $('.f').html( rate);    
});
```

it is parent item's with. So if you rate the .f div's width to parent item's width you get that value.