# Get the width of an element in the units defined in the CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

Lets say I have:

```
.item {
    width: 33%;
}
```

The thing is that if with jQuery I have to retrieve width:

```
$('.item').first().css('width')
```

It returns the actual width in pixels,

How can I get the `%` ? Do I have to calculate based on the actual parent's width?

Comment: AFAIK yes you have to do the calculation :(

Comment: unfortunately yes, you need to calculate. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785951/how-to-get-width-of-a-div-in-percentage-using-jquery

Comment: p.s. was in Deia just last week!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Really? what a Coinkiding!!!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yes!   Was beautiful, took the long winding road down to the Cala and had lunch at the restaurant on the right!  It was beautiful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do calculations

> 100 * (element width / parent element width)

```
var el = $('.item').first(),
    width = (100 * parseFloat(el.css('width')) / parseFloat(el.parent().css('width'))) + '%';
```

or

```
var el = $('.item').first(),
    width = (100 * parseFloat(el.width()) / parseFloat(el.parent().width())) + '%';
```