# jQuery width() function returning the exact percentage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using normal jQuery method to calculate the width of my container, here it is just a div. The div has an id = 'parent-container' with css: **width: 80%;**

But when I try to get the width of the 'parent-container' using, `$('#parent-container').width()` it returns me **80px** as value. Instead it should return **548px**.

I have refered [another stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208951/jquery-width-not-returning-correct-value-on-a-div-with-generated-content) as well, and still no luck to achieve the solution. 
Providing the fiddle of above stackoverflow question.. [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/leeives/ujE6s/)

Please guide me.

Here is my usage:

```
<div class="outer" style:"display:none">
   <div id="parent-container"  expanded="no" ng-if="vm.filter == vm.exists">
        <div id="child"> </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: try to get outer width like this: $('.parent-container').outerWidth(); also you have div with class but in jQuery function you have defined id

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785951/how-to-get-width-of-a-div-in-percentage-using-jquery

Comment: Sanjeev, i have edited it.. Thanks for spotting it out..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Existing fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/leeives/ujE6s/)

Comment: @SureshPMS It's supposed to return the computed width, can you provide a fiddle with your problem. It would help others to play and answer you.

Comment: You are trying to get dimensions from a hidden element in your demo. Of course it won't be what you expect

Comment: yes, i have used to display:none for parent charlietfl

Comment: Well if that is your real app situation you need to rethink what you are trying to do then. If it's not what the situation is then that demo is just wasting our time and effort

Comment: check this, it will help you out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none getting the width of hidden div

Comment: Also you should be doing this in a directive. Code being used here to represent issue is not relevant to an angular app

Answer (score 0):

In your html markup you are using `class="parent-container"` instead ID.

Using `$('.parent-container').width()` should give you the result you want if you are using class.

Comment: Ya that was my mistake. I have corrected it. But even now am facing the issue.