# Change object width with window size with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some span objects that I insert into a table with jQuery with a specific width attribute. I want the widths of these objects to change as the window size changes, as the table has position relative.

Here is my code (The snippet doesn't show the issue very well - changing window size, but it gives an idea of the context):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var var1 = 2
  var element = $('td').filter(function() {
    var holidayText = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(holidayText, 10) == var1;
  });
  //need this to adjust with table size
  var cell_width = element.width();

  var2 = 3;
  var width = var2 * cell_width;

  add_html = element.append('</br><span class="spanclass" style="width: ' + width + 'px; position: absolute"></span>');
});
```

```css
div.class1 {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
  position: relative;
}

span.spanclass {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How do I get a width attribute / assign a new attribute that means this widths scales with the table/window size? Do I use em for this? Or as a percentage width?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `$(window).resize(function() { //do something here });` ?

Comment: if the width is relative to the cell <td> its better to use percentage %

Comment: Might try a resize function. @Chiller how do I use .width() to return a percentage?

Comment: @RuthYoung here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785951/how-to-get-width-of-a-div-in-percentage-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use $(window).resize().

I have changed your script and it's working for me:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/71rd84jy/

Let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why use js in a first place?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var var1 = 2
   var element = $('td').filter(function() {
    var holidayText = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
     return parseInt(holidayText, 10) == var1;
   });
    add_html = element.append('</br><span class="spanclass"></span>');
});
```

```css
div.class1 {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid navy;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6ec;
  position: relative;
}

span.spanclass {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Notice `box-sizing: border-box;` - it make width 100% including 2px of padding, otherwise it would be [2px]+[100%]+[2px]

Comment: I'm using javascript because all the spans have different widths based off a calculation

Comment: @RuthYoung you can simply set non-100% width to each span you want, they will respect parents width.

Comment: Can I get .width() to return a percentage value? Rather than px? @Cheslab

Comment: @RuthYoung No, you should calculate it by yourself. But why do you need to get width when you're setting it?

Comment: the width is a calculation based on the width of a table cell multiplied by the number of cells it needs to cover which is another variable

Comment: @RuthYoung in this case you don't need to operate %. Set implicit width in px one time on document.ready and every time on window.resize